# Why email sending functionality is not working?

Tags: javascript, php, html, email

I want to send an email when someone click on my website's download link. I am working in PHP and JavaScript. The following two snippets are in same file.

#### HTML

```
<form method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email ID" id="email" onchange="check();" require pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label style="font-size:14px;"><input type="checkbox" id="toggle"> I agree to receive emails from MarketerBoard. We will not share your any personal information with anyone.</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" style="min-height:40px;">
      <a style="display:none;" href="/images/docs/EMAIL-MARKETING-GUIDE.pdf" name="downloadBtn" download class="mb-button" id="dwn-btn" onchange="check();" onClick="sendmail();">Get your free guide</a>
  </div>
</form>
```

#### JavaScript

```
if(isset($_POST['downloadBtn']))
{
    $to      = 'examle@example.com';
    $subject = 'the subject';
    $message = 'hello';
    $headers = 'From: example@example.com' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: example@example.com' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);


   //echo 'Email Sent.';
 }
```

I validate the email id of user from using following code. I want to send the email on click of the link, which does not seems to work.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    function check() {     
        document.getElementById("toggle").checked = false;
        var email_x = document.getElementById("email").value;
        filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
        if (filter.test(email.value)) {
            document.getElementById("email").style.border = "2px solid teal";
            var userEmail = document.getElementById('email').value
            $('#toggle').click(function () {
            //check if checkbox is checked
            if ($(this).is(':checked') & filter.test(email.value)) {
                 $("#dwn-btn").show(); } 
                else {
                $("#dwn-btn").hide();}});
                return true;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("email").style.border = "2px solid red";
            $("#dwn-btn").hide();
            return false;
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected.  Edit your question to include the code, please don't add it in a comment, as it will probably be unreadable.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

It is better to show what is actually happening, rather than describing what you expect to happen.

Comment: There are several guides out there showing you how to create a mail feature with JS and PHP. Use your search engine and read to get some knowledge. If you get stuck, then you can come to SO and ask for assistance. We're not a code-writing service.

Comment: i just paste my code on question what i have tried.

Comment: So where is the javascript code for `check()` and `sendmail()`

Comment: So you want us to write the `sendmail()` function for you... right?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check/change your PHP mail configuration:

1. Open your php.ini file
2. Search for the line that reads [mail function]
3. Add/change the details of your mail server. This could be a local mail server or the mail server of your ISP.
4. Save/close the php.ini file
5. Restart your web server

Example code below :

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Send email" />
    <input type="hidden" name="send_mail" value="1" />
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['send_mail']))
{
    $to      = 'nobody@example.com';
    $subject = 'the subject';
    $message = 'hello';
    $headers = 'From: nobody@example.com' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: nobody@example.com' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    echo 'Email Sent.';
}

?>
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to do this with javascript, probably using AJAX

Comment: Sorry Divvya but i'm not using Sumbit button. i'm using here Link.